# Mongodb Single document and array of fields

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a collection structure as below.

```
[
  {
    "userName": "name",
    "userId": "1234",
    "visitedaddr": [
      {
        "addr_id": "xyz",
        "addr_name": "tdl",
        "addr_time": "timestamp",
        "days_spent": [
          {
            "days": "1",
            "visited_clients": "3"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "addr_id": "xyx",
        "addr_name": "tdl",
        "addr_time": "timestamp",
        "days_spent": [
          {
            "days": "1",
            "visited_clients": "3"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "addr_id": "xy1",
        "addr_name": "rjplm",
        "addr_time": "timestamp",
        "days_spent": [
          {
            "days": "1",
            "visited_clients": "3"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

- a user can visit new address and spent some days to visit clients.
- a user can visit same address and spent some days to visit another set of clients.
- addr_id is unique and addr_name is not.

what i want to know is
--> i need to insert new document based on new user/old user.

1. if it is old user I should be able to add new object to the document any number of times based on userId
2. and i should be able to view based on the addr_id for that particular userid
3. If is search for **userId and addr_name** I am ***getting all data for that user***.

   below is the query i have used for 3rd point.

   ```
   db.mycollec
     .find(
       { userId: "1234", "visitedaddr.addr_name": "tdl" },
       {
         projection: {
           _id: 0,
           userName: 1,
           userId: 1,
           "visiteaddr.addr_name": 1,
           "visiteaddr.addr_id": 1
         }
       }
     )
     .toArray();
   ```

below is the response..

```
 {
  "userId": 1234,
  "userName": "name",
  "visitedaddr": [
    {
      "addr_id": "xyz",
      "addr_name": "tdl"
    },
    {
      "addr_id": "xyx",
      "addr_name": "tdl"
    },
    {
      "addr_id": "xy1",
      "addr_name": "rjplm"
    }
  ]
}
```

I am getting complete data. Please help to know about all the three..

thanks..

Comment: what should be the output?

Comment: Output should be as below.
```json
{

  "userId": 1234,
  "userName": "name",
  "visitedaddr": [

    {
      "addr_id": "xyz",
      "addr_name": "tdl"
    },

    {
      "addr_id": "xyx",
      "addr_name": "tdl"
    },

}
```

Comment: You need to use `$filter` aggregation for that

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet i dont want to add new fields for this. i need to fetch the data from db.

Comment: Please check the output first. It will replace your `visitedaddr` fields with the `$filter`ed data